# PHP Search bar does not display data

Tags: php, html, database, search

I must have a problem somewhere with formatting my code but cant find where, 
This is the form I place the search bar in:

```
<form>
        <?php include_once("searchbar.php"); ?>
    </form>
```

This is my search bar code:

```
<form method= "post" action = "search.php">
        <input type="text" name="search_input" placeholder="Search Designer Sofas..." />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

And this is the beginning of the search results page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
   //retrieves the specified element from the URL
   $search_input = $_POST["search_input"];

   include_once("connection_to_db.php");

   //isset function checks if a variable is set
   if(!isset($search_input))
   {
        print("Nothing to search !");
        return;
   }

    //take the books with the specific name
    $query_products = "SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE name LIKE '%".$search_input."%'";

    $query_product_result = mysql_query($query_products)
     or die(mysql_error());

    $num_rows_products = mysql_num_rows($query_product_result);

?>

<html lang="en">

<head>
```

Now what happens is that when I click on the search button the address changes in the url to the search query but the page doesnt, does it mean that it is sending to it but not receiving anything?

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO, with prepared statements, or [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is going to wreck your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have nested `<form>` elements. This is how your form is rendering:

```
<form>
<form method= "post" action = "search.php">
        <input type="text" name="search_input" placeholder="Search Designer Sofas..." />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</form>
```

The second form (the one with the action) will be ignored. Remove the `<form>` wrapper where you include `searchbar.php`.

You're also wide open to SQL injection attacks. Consider using [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: That seemed to work the charm, searches but the results are hidden

Answer (score 0):

enter = sign for action

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="search_input" placeholder="Search Designer Sofas..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

and try to remove form tags from

```
<?php include_once("searchbar.php"); ?>
```

Comment: I was really hoping that was it, but it just does the same thing. Just the url changes to /index.php?search_input=asd the page doesnt change

Comment: did you try ctrl+f5 or ctrl+r on the form page and then submit the form again?

Comment: yup, uploaded again on the server just in case, still nothing

Comment: I checked your answer, still just changes the url

Comment: please paste your source code which generated by your browser... then we will find the problem